# Deserializing Map<Object, Object> with GSon

Tags: java, object, gson

I have a Map containing a mixture of types like in this simple example

```
final Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", "a");
map.put("c", 2);
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final String string = gson.toJson(map);
final Type type = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
final Map<Object, Object> map2 = gson.fromJson(string, type);
for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

What I get back are plain `Object`s, no `Integer`s, no `String`s. The output looks like

```
a : java.lang.Object@48d19bc8
b : java.lang.Object@394a8cd1
c : java.lang.Object@4d630ab9
```

Can I fix it somehow? I'd expect that such simple cases will be handled correctly by default.

<sup>I know that the information about the type can't always be preserved, and possibly `1` and `"1"` means exactly the same in JSON. However, returning plain content-less objects just makes no sense to me.</sup>

**Update:** The serialized version (i.e. the `string` above) looks fine:

```
{"a":1,"b":"a","c":2}
```

Comment: Could you look at what the `final  String string` looks like? I am sure it would help in understanding the problem.

Comment: I've just encountered this as well... That is why I use my JSONer... it might be a bit slower, but it far more generic than Gson: http://nu-art-infrastructure.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/jsoner.html

Comment: @TacB0sS: I've followed the "clear and static data structure" advice instead. However, making Gson handle this should be pretty trivial. Do you care to file an issue?

Comment: The terrible thing about this, it that I use GSON with Android, and on my phone it works well, while on other phones it creates what you have described... My solution was also the clear and static, but in the JSONer parser you can use maps and lists with nested complex objects, and it is all solved within the annotation!

Comment: Care to file an issue about what? they know about this issue don't they?

Comment: @TacB0sS: How should I know if they know? :D I can't recall any such issue, so maybe they know but with nobody complaining they don't care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gson isn't that smart. Rather provide a clear and static data structure in flavor of a Javabean class so that Gson understands what type the separate properties are supposed to be deserialized to.

E.g.

```
public class Data {
    private Integer a;
    private String b;
    private Integer c;
    // ...
}
```

in combination with

```
Data data1 = new Data(1, "a", 2);
String json = gson.toJson(data1);
Data data2 = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments, the keyset seems to be not fixed (although you seem to be able to convert it manually afterwards without knowing the structure beforehand). You could create a [custom deserializer](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer). Here's a quick'n'dirty example.

```
public class ObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String value = element.getAsString();
        try {
            return Long.valueOf(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

which you use as follows:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new ObjectDeserializer()).create();
// ...
```

Comment: A Javabean is surely not possible, as the key set is not fixed. As a workaround I can use `Map<String, String>` and convert the types manually (something like that), I just wonder why GSon behaves that strangely.

Comment: The ability to convert the types manually suggests that you know the data structure beforehand. So the argument that keyset is not fixed is a non-argument. As to Gson, you could consider a custom deserializer which determines if the value is a number (regex, parser, `Long#valueOf()`, etc) and returns either `Long` or `String`. See also http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

Comment: I updated the answer with an example, you may find it useful.

Comment: *"So the argument that keyset is not fixed is a non-argument."* - This "non-argument" makes the Javabean solution void. But thx for the `ObjectDeserializer` example, it works nice.

Comment: So the argument that a Javabean is not possible is a non-argument ;)

Comment: Assuming a Map is a Javabean, yes. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new JsonDeserializer<Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonPrimitive value = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if (value.isBoolean()) {
          return value.getAsBoolean();
        } else if (value.isNumber()) {
          return value.getAsNumber();
        } else {
          return value.getAsString();
        }
      }
    }).create();
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade to [Gson 2.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). It prints this:

```
a : 1.0
b : a
c : 2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You are storing the data in a Map.  It looks like you need to cast the object to the type you need.

Comment: For sure not, if the type was `String` or `Integer`, it couldn't output `java.lang.Object@...`. I also double checked it using `getClass()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a JSON string from `Map<Object, Object>`, I think `json-simple` is better choice than `Gson`.

This is a brief example from http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples :

```
//import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
//import java.util.Map;
//import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
obj.put("name","foo");
obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
obj.put("nickname",null);
String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(obj);
System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Result: `{"name":"foo","num":100,"balance":1000.21,"is_vip":true,"nickname":null}`

For decoding, refer to http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples .