# gson: parametrized fromJson depending on the Type

Tags: java, json, casting, gson

I'm sorry it was surely already asked, but I did not find what I need
I have several message types:

```
class AbstractMessage {
    int code;
    String token;
}

class ShareMessage extends AbstractMessage{
    String user;
    Map<String, String> friends;
}

class PostMessage extends AbstractMessage{
    String user;
    Map<String, String> data;
}
```

and a method to decode them from the json post message:

```
public Object getMessage(BufferedReader r, Type t){
    Object o = null;
    try{
        o = g.fromJson(r, t);
    } catch (final JsonSyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Error in Json format", e);
    } catch (final JsonParseException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Error in parsing Json", e);
    }

    return o;
}
```

then for example:

```
Type dataType = new TypeToken<PostMessage>() {}.getType();
PostMessage m = (PostMessage) getMessage(request.getReader(), dataType);
```

works, but it's ugly, how can I have a parametrized getMessage function, or anything better than returning Object and casting
thx

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396578/deserializing-mapobject-object-with-gson

Comment: yes close, I'd need to put a jsondeserializer based on the `Type t` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<T>` to the method signature, immediately before the return type. This creates a type-parameterized method:

```
public <T> T getMessage(BufferedReader r, TypeToken<T> typeToken){
  try {
    return g.fromJson(r, typeToken.getType());
  } catch (final JsonSyntaxException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Error in Json format", e);
  } catch (final JsonParseException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Error in parsing Json", e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
PostMessage m = getMessage(request.getReader(), new TypeToken<PostMessage>() {});
```