# Pass Type to method and alter response

Tags: java, json, gson

I am receiving JSON from a call from Java, and I want to parse it to an object that has a 'info' property, that will change type according to who made the call.

```
public <T> ExternalCallBaseResult<T> parseExternalResultJson(String res)
{
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ExternalCallBaseResult<T>>(){}.getType();
    return Global.gson.fromJson(res, collectionType);
}
```

I would like to call this method like this:

```
ExternalCallBaseResult<GetUserInfoResult_Info> result = global.parseExternalResultJson(res);
```

Given the class:

```
public static class ExternalCallBaseResult<T>
{
    public int callbackid = 0;
    public int success = 1;
    public T info = null;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.cht.params.Params$GetUserInfoResult_Info
```

EDIT:
I saw this question with an answer: [gson: parametrized fromJson depending on the Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280837/gson-parametrized-fromjson-depending-on-the-type?rq=1)
But is there no way to make without having to send the TypeToken on the method call?

Comment: you tried using class<?> type?

Comment: DO you mean passing a second parameter like 'Class<T> genericType'?

Comment: yea something like that then use Class#cast

Comment: How would I use it on the body of the method? I tried having that parameter, but if I use it anwhere it asks me to create a class from it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood what you're trying to acheive, when I commented earlier I thought it was something else but now I think I understand,
how about something like this?

```
public ExternalCallBaseResult<?> parseExternalResultJson(String res)
{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(getType());
    return ExternalCallBaseResult(c.cast(Global.gson.fromJson(res))); 
}
```

edit:
ok im not 100% sure I understand what you mean so i'll try giving an example and tell me if im right or not

say we have a class

```
class A<T> {
     T t;
     A(T t) {this.t=t;}
}
```

and we have a function foo that we want it to return A but SomeActualType is not known untill running time where we get it from some json

```
public A<?> foo(String json) {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(getTypeFromJson(json)); //this will load the class of the required type
    Object o = parseJson(json); //say this parses the json and returns some object according to it
    A a = new A(c.cast(o));
    return a;
)
```

now foo will return A that contains the type we received from the json (I omitted stuff like try catch or throws declaration)

hope this helps

Comment: Kinda like that, but the 'fromJson' method asks for a Class type as second parameter. And that getType() call is defined where? (Did not know about the "Class<?>" thing, gonna look into it.)

Comment: so pass c to the fromJson and inside it to the casting

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you explained, or how to use what you posted. Could you post a more thoroughly explained example?