# Object mapper from and to json

Tags: json, jackson, json.net

I am developing an application system that has multiple executable applications on different platforms (java and .net).

For communication between them I am using **JSON** format. So I need to map object to and from json very frequently. Current solution (seems workaround) is jackson at java end and Newtonsoft.Json at .NET end. Problem is property name are not same and not all properties will be required at de-serialization end

So my questions are:

1. Is there any mapper to do this. 
      Currently using NewtonSoft.JSON.DatasetMapper at .Net end and 
      jsonanysetter annotation at java, but in this approach mapping 
      definition is loaded for each object as actual object mapping code
      is in code. For example:

```
  //C#
  myobj.prop1 = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["propertyName1"].ToString();
  // and so on.....

  //Java
  switch(key)
  {
      case "prop1":
             myobj.setPropery1(value.toString());
             break;
      //and so on......
  }
```

2. Object transformationRate needs to be very high as object are 
       sent and recieved at very high speed. say some 10k objects per second.

Answer (score 0):

We used GSON in one of our project , i think [this reference](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types) may help you, Apart from it ,there is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396578/deserializing-mapobject-object-with-gson) question may help you. [another q/a in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596667/how-to-invoke-default-deserialize-with-gson)

Comment: but using "TypeAdapterFactory class" still I need to map object in code. Same I am already doing. As many property names in both objects are different and needs mapping.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish you might also check Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/ lib, it provides pojo databinding and streaming api. However if you want to map a json structure to a completly different pojo structure (not only different names) the only solution is to use streaming or dom api.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Jackson.  It's the *de facto* JSON library for Java and will happily handle turning objects into JSON and back again.  It has many options to allow you to alter the output, and most per-object configuration is carried out using annotations so is visible in your model rather than hidden away in a separate configuration file.